# Production для front-end и backend сервисов

Tags: java, reactjs, rest, spring-boot

Я разрабатываю приложение, которые имеет два отдельных сервиса. 
Один из них -> `create-react-app`, который воспроизводится на порте `3000`, другой `spring boot rest API service`, работающий на `8080`.

На данный момент я просто настроила прокси для передачи данных.

Хочу попробовать задеплоить два сервиса в production.
Прочитала много статей и поняла, что не совсем понятна конфигурация.

1. Думаю воспользоваться Heroku, но может быть есть еще какие-нибудь неплохие сервисы?
2. Так же как скофигурировать процесс передачи данных для production, чтобы мне это в то же время не мешало тестировать приложение локально.
3. Как настроить, чтобы два сервиса имело один domain.
4. Есть ли интересные примеры/статьи именно с моим случаем? (Искала, много было примеров когда react и springboot в одном проекте, с использование плагина для spring boot, но не нашла хорошиз статей для раздельных сервисов)

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что есть приложение spring boot, которое предоставляет данные, и react-app, которое отображает данные.

Есть 2 подхода для реализации такой системы в production:

1. React приложение компилируется в js файлы - статические файлы. Разворачивается nginx, который по определенному урлу отдает на запросы статические файлы, а по другому урлу запросы перенаправляются на api.
2. React приложение компилируется в js файлы - статические файлы. Эти файлы копируется в приложение Spring Boot в каталог resources/static. И таким образом приложение spring boot и обслуживает статику и отдает данные для отображения.

Теперь по вопросам:

1. Можно арендовать сервер VPS, это вроде дешевле чем Heroku
2. Тут больше вопрос настройки react приложения. Обычно указывается адрес получения данных. В данные момент вы настроили отправку запросов через прокси nodejs сервер на spring(так в продакшене не делают), необходимо предусмотреть возможность задание url напрямую к spring приложению.
3. В каждом из этих 2 вариантов будет один домен.
4. По [2 варианту обслуживание статики](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) и [по 1 варианту](https://toster.ru/q/323047)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Если можно, то у меня возник еще один вопрос. имеет ли смысл вообще заморачиваться с двумя сервисами, если можно просто сделать по подобию туториала https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/ ? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: По моему опыту, spring data rest использовать в продакшене плохой вариант. Потому всегда появляется функциональность, которую становится не возможно реализовать. Например по пользователю фильтровать данные или как-то ещё. 1 вариант на самом деле лучше. Потому что в коммерческой разработке часто есть отдельные front и back разработчики. И этот вариант позволяет добиться слабой связанности работы разработчиков.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо.